# Using side_effect for mocking in python attributes

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

When I use a `mock.return_value.method.side_effect = [1, 2]`.

It works perfect.
I get in each call `1`, and then `2` in next call.

But, how can I do it for attributes?

I use `object.text = "some-text"`. And works. But I need a side_effect for the attribute `text`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a [PropertyMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) object.  Attaching it to your Mock has to be done a little different than normal.  Here is an example:

```
from mock import Mock
from mock import PropertyMock

object = Mock()
type(object).attribute = PropertyMock(side_effect=[1, 2])

print object.attribute
print object.attribute
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you. Can you explain me why the use of `type` in object?

Comment: I haven't dug into their implementation, so I'm not entirely sure, but the linked docs say "Because of the way mock attributes are stored you can’t directly attach a PropertyMock to a mock object. Instead you can attach it to the mock type object"

Comment: Oh, I see... Thank you!